# zero conditional versus first conditional

Tags: grammar

> If the tree isn't watered, it (dies - will die).

This sentence seems very confusing to me, I don't know whether to choose **dies** or **will die** because zero conditional is used when the result will always happen. I heard from a friend of mine that if we talk about specific things we use first conditional. 
What's the best choice for this sentence?

Comment: Either one could be correct, depending on context.

Comment: @PeterShor Here is the context : If the tree isn't watered, it (dies - will die).

Comment: That's not context. What are the sentences before this one? Nobody comes up to you and says *"If the tree isn't watered, it dies."* At least, not to me.

Comment: Context 1: *"Acme nurseries has been doing great business selling apple trees. But they don't sell them with adequate instructions, so the people buying them are getting ripped off. They plant their tree, and expect it to grow by itself. But in this climate, if the tree isn't watered, it dies."*

Comment: Context 2: *"When I'm on vacation, make sure you feed my cats and water my apple tree. If the tree isn't watered, it will die."*

Comment: @PeterShor If this was on an Exam, what would you choose?

Comment: This is no different than being asked to choose, without any further explanation, between *left* and *right*.

Comment: @Mohamed: my point is that both answers to this question are valid. So you have to guess which context the person who created the exam was thinking of. (My guess is *will die*.) This isn't testing your English skills.